# UML - Use Case - Identify not registered user and registered users

Tags: uml

I'm planning to write a service of event handling (like Google's Doodle) and, in the use case diagram, I need to distinguish between registered users and not registered users.
At first, I thought that:

> Registered User _ is generalization of _ Not Registered User

with the following actions:

> Not Registered User ---> Registration to the service
>
> Not Registered User ---> Partecipate to an event
>
> Registered User ---> Login to the service

But I don't know if I didn't understand the theory behind use cases:
should I use only one actor ("User") and associate him all the actions,
or keep this generalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actor** can be seen as the **ROLE** a user plays in a system. From this statement it is already clear that the single actor ("User") version does not model your situation correctly.

**Generalization** between two actors gives the specialized actor access to all the use cases associated with his parent-actor. In your case I would not say that this is the case. Maybe they even have some common use cases, but they both have use cases that do not make sense for the other one. For example:

- Not registered user cannot login.
- Registered user cannot registrate

They roles in the system are simply very different and therefore a generalization is not the perfect solution eihter.

I would simply make 2 separate actors, that eventualy share some use cases. I will assume that Not registered user can also participate in an event (maybe restricted), just to show that they can share some use cases, without the need to use generalization:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say that registered and unregistered user are states of user. Actor is a behaviored classifier and can have states. I think that there is only actor named "User". Use constraints to associations connected to user and usecase to restrict user participating on individual usecase. See example below:

[image]

Comment: The beauty of UML is in its flexibility and creativity it unleashes. There are many solutions to a same problem and it's our task to find the perfect one. I find your solution too complicated and confusing. The idea is to clarify the situation visually as much as possible, making intuitive diagrams and then giving additional info just to espose the details. Changing the internal state of an Actor and explaining it in additional restrictions to associations is probably unclear to the most of the readers. And whem more UCs are added, these restrictions must always be there.

Comment: This solution is correct and clear. Please read UML specification to get more information about usecase semantic. Constraints are very common elements in UML models, but people often do not understand it.

Comment: you should read my comment better. I said excactly that - your model is correct, but people will probably not understand it. :) The main point of modelling is (still) communication and exchange of ideas and specifications. If your model is complicated and besides, uses the elements that people "do not understand", than you simply missed the main point.